# :"ErrorException","message":"Undefined index: image_Name","file":"E:\\xampp new\\htdocs\\system\\app\\controllers\\AccountController.php","line":293}}

Tags: php, ajax

i will get exception that is

> {"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined index:
>   image_Name","file":"E:\xampp
>   new\htdocs\system\app\controllers\AccountController.php","line":293}}

**this is my html form**

```
<form role="form" method="PATCH" action="{{URL::route('staff-new')}}" id="post-form">
                  <div class="box-body floating_block">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">User Name</label>
                      <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">User Display Name</label>
                      <input type="text" name="display_Name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Confirm Password</label>
                      <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" >
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
                      <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Phone</label>
                      <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">User Designation</label>
                      <select type="text" name="user_Role" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter Category Name">

                      @foreach($designation as $key=>$data)
                      <option value="{{$key}}">{{$data}}</option>
                       @endforeach
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" >
                      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Profile Image</label>
                      <input type="file" name="image_Name" class="form-control" id="" accept="image/*">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-form-ajax-validation submit_btn">Submit</button>
```

**this is my ajax code**

```
$(document).on('click', '.submit-form-ajax-validation', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var fonturl = $('#post-form').attr('action');
    var method=$('#post-form').attr('method');
    //alert(fonturl);
    $.ajax({
    url : fonturl,
    type: method,
    data: $('#post-form').serialize(),
    async: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
        if(data.msg=="Yes")
        {
             $(document).trigger('showMessage','<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="cross_icon_rq" ><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o cross_icon_cs" class=""></i></a><div class="text_success_cs"><strong>Success!</strong><br />'+data.text+'</div>');
             $('#post-form').reset;
        }else if(data.msg=="No")
        {
             $(document).trigger('showMessage','<a href="javascript:void(0)"  id="cross_icon_rq"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o cross_icon_cs" class=""></i></a><div class="text_error_cs"><strong>Error!</strong><br /> '+data.text+'</div>'); 


        }else if(data.msg=="validation_error")  
        {
            var msg='';
                  $.each(data.error, function(index,element)                                
                        {

                              //console.log(element);
                                if(index.length>0)
                                    {
                                        $('#'+index).addClass('validation_error_cs');
                                        //console.log(response[error][index2]);
                                        msg=msg+element+'<br />';
                                    }


                        });
                        $('.responseMessage_rq').removeClass('error_block_cs');
                        $('.responseMessage_rq').removeClass('success_block_cs');
                        $('.responseMessage_rq').addClass('error_block_cs');
                        $(document).trigger('showMessage','<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="cross_icon_rq" ><i class="subhocross1 cross_icon_cs" ></i></a><div class="text_error_cs"><div class="text_heading_cs"><strong>Error!</strong></div>'+ msg+'</div>');    
        }   

    }
    });
});
```

**this is my controller**

```
                if($input['image_Name']!='')
                {
                    $filename = $_FILES['image_Name'];
                    if (!empty($filename))
                    {
                      $filename = Input::file('image_Name')->getClientOriginalName(); 
                      $splitName = explode(".", $filename);

                      $fileExt = end($splitName);
                      $newFileName  = strtolower('profile_image_'.time().'.'.$fileExt);
                      //
                      $destinationPath = base_path(). '/public/uploads/profile_image/';
                      //dd($destinationPath);
                      if(!file_exists($destinationPath))
                      {
                          mkdir($destinationPath,0777,true);
                      }
                      $rules = array('myfile'  => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png');
                      $size = Input::file('image_Name')->getSize();

                      $data = array('myfile' => Input::file('image_Name'));

                      $validation = Validator::make($data,$rules);
                       //dd($size);
                        if ($validation->fails())
                        {
                            $response['Success']="format_na";
                              return $response;
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because the form attribute enc-type is missing

Pass:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```

enc-type is mandatory for file upload

Comment: look $filename = Input::file('image_Name')->getClientOriginalName(); , it could be named to lower case, like "image_name"